# How can I set the rotation origin for a canvas pattern using a DOMMatrix?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using a combination of `pattern` and `DOMMatrix` to rotate a texture on a canvas, at the moment the transform origin seems to be set to the x:0 y:0 point on the canvas. I've looked through as much documentation as I can find, but I can't seem to see any way to change this. Is there a way to set the transform origin for a `DOMMatrix`?

Please note: I specifically don't want to rotate the canvas context if I can avoid it. I am trying to rotate the filled pattern, not the shape it's filling (And in the real version it's a complex shape rather than a rectangle, so working out the "counter rotated" points would add a significant amount complexity that I hope isn't necessary)

Simplified example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var rotation = 0
var pattern = null
var matrix = new DOMMatrix()

function draw() {
  // Rotate
  rotation += 0.15
  if (rotation > 360) {
    rotation = 0
  }
  pattern.setTransform(matrix.rotate(rotation))

  // Fill
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80)

  // Loop
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

// Load the image
var img = new Image()
img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/1044/100/100'
img.onload = function() {
  pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat')
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a matrix this is usually done by translating the matrix to the desired origin, rotating the matrix and lastly translate it back to the original position. The order is important!

Unfortunately the `DOMMatrix` isn't well documented. I figured you can do this by chaining the `.translate()` and `.rotate()` operations. Since the matrix is suited for 2d and 3d operations the translate method expects x, y and z coordinates.

So for a rotation around the center we need to translate it to the center of the canvas.

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rotation = 0;
var pattern = null;
var matrix = new DOMMatrix();

var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var pattern2 = null;
var matrix2 = new DOMMatrix();

function draw() {
  rotation += 0.15
  if (rotation > 360) {
    rotation = 0
  }

  pattern.setTransform(matrix.translate(85, 50, 0).rotate(rotation).translate(-85, -50, 0));
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80);

  pattern2.setTransform(matrix2.rotate(rotation));
  ctx2.fillStyle = pattern2;
  ctx2.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

// Load the image
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/1044/100/100';
img.onload = function() {
  pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  pattern2 = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="100" width="170" style="float: left;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" height="100" width="170"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't realise that method could be applied to the matrix instead of the context, perfect, thanks.